# Get real time CPU usage of linux process with single line command and as a simple result

Tags: linux, centos, monitoring, centos6, cpu-usage

I've searched everywhere and found nothing about this. I'm trying to create a small gauge that shows the CPU usage of one process specified by PID.

I need the command to print a simple answer , hence why top -p $pid isn't good. The command is executed by PHP and needs to print the response immediately.

Something that is closely related to what I need is

```
sudo ps -p $pid -o %cpu
```

But after testing and searching some more I found out this prints the average usage since the process started. I need the real time usage from the moment the command si ran, like it shows on top.

Is this possible?

edit::

```
$cmd = 'sudo sh -c "top -n1 | awk \'/30100/ {print $9}\'"';
echo exec($cmd);
```

tried without shell

```
$cmd = "sudo top -n1 | awk '/30100/ {print $9}'";
echo exec($cmd);
```

still no result, it doesn't echo anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would start off with the naive approach like so:

```
$ top |grep %pid
```

On ubuntu 12.04, it outputs the line for the PID once per update of top:

```
    username@usrver / $ top |grep 2593
 2593 username   20   0 1103m 170m  16m S   30  2.2  67:25.38 chrome             
 2593 username   20   0 1103m 170m  16m S   28  2.2  67:26.24 chrome             
 2593 username   20   0 1103m 170m  16m S   30  2.2  67:27.15 chrome             
 2593 username   20   0 1103m 170m  16m S   23  2.2  67:27.86 chrome             
 2593 username   20   0 1103m 170m  16m S   25  2.2  67:28.60 chrome
```

Then grab the 10th field with awk, although, we don't really need to use grep here. awk can regex for your PID, then print the CPU value:

```
username@usrver / $ top | awk '/2593/ {print $10}'
25
29
30
32
```

Comment: Works like a charm when I type it into the terminal, but PHP doesn't print anything. Am I doing something wrong? edited OP with some snippets

Comment: Well, i'm not really a PHP programmer, but it looks like you're echoing the return value of exec($cmd), rather than capturing the output of $cmd.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: @AronH. see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

Though the question is already answered and accepted, I think its incomplete. There are a few points missing from the accepted answer.

1. You need to run top in batch mode using -b if you are running it as a child process and want to grab any meaningful output. If not it will have a mix of control characters as a result of running in interactive mode.
2. Specify the number of iterations you want, using -n, otherwise it will result in infinite iteration and the child process will never finish. You need to have at least two iterations, so that top will have a reference point to collect the difference, which is the actual CPU usage.
3. Specify the interval between iterations using -d. On most systems, the default value is 3 seconds. So if you want a per second usage, you need to specify it explicitly.

Now combining all the above points, you get

```
top -b -n 2 -d 1
```

As we have two iterations, we need to consider the second output only. Use awk to get the second output, which starts with string **top**.

```
top -b -n 2 -d 1 | awk '/^top/{i++}i==2'
```

Now lets filter out the PID, say 2593 and print the 9th column, which contains the CPU usage. Only consider output lines that starts with PID.

```
top -b -n 2 -d 1 | awk '/^top/{i++}i==2' | awk '/^\s*2593/ {print $9}'
```